# Replacing a drop down list in MVC with a URL parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a bit of theoretical question because I'm not quite sure where to start coding this one also making it to difficult to Google. I have two models, an Account Model and a Novel model and I've used code first development to set it all up so far.

I've created an 'Add Novel' view by using Entity Framework to make a 'Create' view and for the account id foreign key it's made a drop down list which is correct, but what I want to be able to do is select this value based on a value passed in through the routing so it's automatically added when creating the novel object.

I'm guessing this means I need to change the routes in the route config, but not sure how and not sure how I'd register this as the account id at the time of creating the object so any help with this would be welcome.

Comment: No need to modify the routing. Just make you method `Create(int id)` and navigate to it using `../Novel/Create/#` where  `#` is the Account ID

Comment: Works like a charm - thanks - if you want to pop that in as the answer I'll mark it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to modify the routing. You can use the default routing by changing your `Create()` method to accept the account ID

```
public NovelController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Create(int ID)
  {
    // Get the account based on the value of ID
    // Initialize a new Novel view model and set the parent account properties you need to display in the view
    // return the view
 }
```

and then navigate to it using `../Novel/Create/#` where `#` is the ID of the account, for example in an account 'Details' view, you might have

```
@model Account
...
@Html.ActionLink("Create Novel", "Create" "Novel", new { id = Model.AccountID })
```